# size and positioning not working

Tags: css, responsive-design

i intended to create a responsive design so i set all the objects and divs on my page to %% but they don't respond to the height and width attributes. I figured I should make it a fixed width site instead but that turned out even worse. the objects don't respond to position either. here is a mockup of what it should look like
http://postimg.org/image/yzgfp0x0d/

[here is my css on fiddle][1]

i wonder what could be wrong

[1]: https://js fiddle.net/nmeri17/L9bkmzg7/3/

Comment: Due to the fact, that yuo only used images on your site, the fiddle is really hard to debug

Comment: @Alex the url with images and code is at http://my-name.orgfree.com

Comment: I don't want to offend you but what You need is to learn the basics of css before even starting your own web: I would spend a few hours on http://www.w3schools.com/css/ (and better if a few days) because basically your web atm has no fix at all except remade from scratch. But as few tips, Don't use images where you can use html and in you follow your design (which is not bad) Use maybe images as backgrounds but the text (at the very least at the menú) should be html text. Position the containers (div's, li's) Not the content inside and dont' get discouraged

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I've finished the course on w3schools. This is my ist website in practice. Will get better with time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there are some various problems:

You format elements, that are wrapped in other elements which are the ones you should format. Example:

```html
<ul>
    <li><img class="coupon" src="meet.png" alt=coupon>an image</li>
    <li><img class="coupon1" src="quote.png" alt=coupon1></li>
    <li><img class="coupon2" src="brief.png" alt=coupon2></li>
</ul>
```

Here you assign a float:left; to the coupons, with the effect, that they will be floated left inside the `<li>`-Tags, which are formatted underneath each other.

Also your Setup isn't optimal. With you bodybg.png you have really poor chances for making this site responsible.

Maybe you want to take [this](http://jsfiddle.net/t36o56fL/) as a little orientation.
However, trying things out by yourself should give the most learning success.

Comment: apologies @alex. i had forgotten to update the files on my site. the list part was used in a desperate attempt to find a solution to my many problems. however, i have updated it.can you explain better what you mean about my bodybg

Comment: you're amazing. I've been trying to figure this out for four months now. Does the article element replace the container div?? Thanks for the compliment on my design. I appreciate

Comment: Nah, not completely. Maybe you want go through the elements and add 1px borders to them one by one to see which element is displayed how and where in the browser. Cheers.

Comment: i have updated it but i have a few issues with compatiblity. please check the link at my-name.orgfree.com